# How do I assign each list item to a different pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of four strings and a list of four dataframes. I want to assign each string as each of the dataframes. E.g.

```
list_of_strings = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4']
```

I want each of those to be a dataframe from another list:

```
list_of_dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
```

I can do this manually by typing `string1 = list_of_dfs[0]`, but is there a quicker, more scalable way of doing this with something like a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better here is create dictionary of `DataFrame`s:

```
list_of_strings = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4']
list_of_dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

d = dict(zip(list_of_strings, list_of_dfs))
```

And tne select by keys:

```
print (d['string1'])
print (d['string2'])
```